# Crash when NSPredicate matching strings with parenthesis

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nspredicate

My app is consistently crashing when I try to run an NSPredicate with a string containing a parenthesis. Here is the example code:

```
NSString *myString = @"test)";
NSPredicate *defaultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title MATCHES[cd] %@", myString];
```

Here is the resulting crash log:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Can't do regex matching, reason: Can't open pattern U_REGEX_MISMATCHED_PAREN (string test, pattern test), case 1, canon 2)
```

In my use case people should not be searching strings with parenthesis so I can sanitize the string by doing something like the code below but that is not elegant.

```
myString = [[myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
```

Any help or clues will be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Will your users use regular expressions? If not you should not use `MATCHES` in the first place. How about [`CONTAINS` or `LIKE`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-215868)?

Comment: @MatthiasBauch you are absolutely right. Thank you! I am looking for an absolute match so instead of like or contains I changed it to "title ==[cd] %@" and it is working correctly. So it must be NSPredicate treating the query like a REGEX that's causing the crash. If you want to form your comment as an answer I can go ahead an accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MATCHES` is used for regular expression comparisons. Your expression is treated as a regular expression. And it will fail if your expression isn't a valid regex. So you generally don't want unfiltered user-input if you use `MATCHES`, because it will fail every time an incomplete regex is used.

Maybe one of the other [String Comparison](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-215868) would be better.

> String comparisons are, by default, case and diacritic sensitive. You can modify an operator using the key characters c and d within square braces to specify case and diacritic insensitivity respectively, for example `firstName BEGINSWITH[cd] $FIRST_NAME`.
>
> **BEGINSWITH**
>   The left-hand expression begins with the right-hand expression.
>
> **CONTAINS**
>   The left-hand expression contains the right-hand expression.
>
> **ENDSWITH**
>   The left-hand expression ends with the right-hand expression.
>
> **LIKE**
>   The left hand expression equals the right-hand expression: ? and * are allowed as wildcard characters, where ? matches 1 character and * matches 0 or more characters.
>
> **MATCHES**
>   The left hand expression equals the right hand expression using a regex-style comparison according to ICU v3 (for more details see the ICU User Guide for Regular Expressions).